# how to generate 403 error code in symfony before filter

Tags: php, symfony, event-listener

i'm trying to use the before filter of symfony 2.7 to do authentication. my event listener is as follows

```
class TokenListener {                                                                                                  
protected $dm;                                                                                                     

function __construct() {                                                                                           
}                                                                                                                  
public function setDocumentManager(DocumentManager $dm) {                                                          
    $this->dm = $dm;                                                                                               
}                                                                                                                  

public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event) {                                                 
    $controller = $event->getController();                                                                         

    if (!is_array($controller)) {                                                                                  
        return;                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                              

    if ($controller[0] instanceof TokenAuthenticatedController) {                                                  


        $content = $event->getRequest()->getContent();                                                                                                                           

        $json = json_decode($content,true);                                                                        
        $authId = $json['authId'];                                                                                 
        $authToken = $json['authToken'];                                                                           

        echo "authId: {$authId}, authToken: {$authToken}\n";                                                       

        $user = $this->dm->getRepository('HcUserBundle:User')                                                      
            ->createQueryBuilder()                                                                                 
            ->field('authId')->equals($authId)                                                                      
            ->getQuery()                                                                                           
            ->getSingleResult();                                                                                   


        if (!isset($user) || $user->getAuthToken() != $authToken) {                                                
            throw new AccessDeniedException('This action needs a valid token!');                                   
        }                                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                              
}                                                                                                                  
}
```

but i got 500 error, and symfony error log says

> Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException: "This action needs a valid token!"

instead of getting a 403 error, I also tried to use the `AccessDeniedHttpException` and have the same problem, does anyone know how to generate a 403 response here? Thanks

Comment: The documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html#creating-an-event-listener) shows this code, so probably it is correct :) The error says that there is no listener able to catch "AccessDeniedException", maybe you didn't configure a valid firewall?

Comment: You probably needed to throw a Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException not a Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException

Answer (score 1):

you can also just return a new response, setting the status code to `Codes::HTTP_FORBIDDEN`

```
return new Response("This action needs a valid token!", Codes::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
```

EDIT: nope this might not work since your in a listener ...

EDIT: are you sure it produces a 500 in your prod env aswell,   not just on app_dev

EDIT:    it SHOULD work this way, in a listener :

```
$response = new RedirectResponse("someUri", Codes::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
$event->setResponse($response);
```